# Creating array of class objects of varying sizes

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I have several sprite objects of different sizes I would like to turn into an array, but cannot get the declarations right. Nothing I search for seems to cover this particular situation.

How do I code circle and square into mySprites[0] and mySprites[1] or Sprite[0].mySprites or ?? Does the variable size of each sprite preclude this? If they were all set to a fixed size how would I code it?

P.S. The Arduino does NOT support vectors.

Current code

sprite.h:

```
Class Sprite{
    Public:
    Sprite::Sprite (int _width, int _height, row_byte, ...);
     (more code)
}
```

ArduinoDemo.ino:

```
#include "sprite.h"

Sprite circle = Sprite {4,4,
 0b0110,
 0b1001,
 0b1001,
 0b0110};

Sprite square = Sprite {6,6,
(and so on)
```

Comment: `Class Sprite{
    Public:` Note that c++ is case sensitive! Also I don't see any array declared in your code??

Comment: How about an array of pointers to `Sprite`?